# Get all hidden commits still on Github after a "push -f origin"

Tags: git, github

I've been working on a new version of one of my opensource libraries and started a new local git repo. Then, I added the remote of the existing repo on Github as `origin` and then `push -f origin` without doing a `git pull` first.

I don't know what I was thinking... but of course that overwrote what was on Github and wiped out the history completely.

I'm now trying to fix my mistake and restore everything as it was before the `push -f`.

I have another copy of the repo checked out on a different machine but unfortunately it's not up to date to the latest commit and therefore I can't use it to restore the repo on Github.

However I tried to use the SHA1 to build the URL below and to my surprise, the commit is still on Github somewhere.

https://github.com/flubbermedia/FMAboutPanel/commit/dac457220b33e33583569d5ced129d2c60d1bcca

So... my question is... Is there any way to get a list of commits available on Github? Unfortunately it looks like this 'lost' commits don't get downloaded when you clone the repo locally... they are available only on the Github server.

Any idea?

Comment: From the box in which you initiated the force push, `git reflog` is likely your best shot.

Comment: `git fsck` can give you information on the inaccessible commits.

Comment: I think getting access to dangling commits needs administrative access, first thing I'd try here is contact github support

Comment: @Makoto @choroba unfortunately I initialised a new local repo when I started to work on the new version of the library. Hence `reflog` and `fsck` don't contain any useful info.

Comment: @jthill Thanks... I thought about that but I wanted to understand if there was a way to do it without bothering them :)

Comment: In this scenario there isn't anything you can do.  Since you've force-pushed and lost the original trace of history, Git will act as if that had been the history all along and there were no other dangling commits around.

Comment: I followed @jthill advice and wrote to github support. They quickly pointed me to the commit at the tip of master just before my `push -f`. From there I could create a new branch with everything in it. It is now available here: https://github.com/flubbermedia/FMAboutPanel/tree/pre-cocoapods

Answer (score 0):

If you have the last commit sha id, you can try something like this:

```
git fetch origin
git reset --hard dac457220b33e33583569d5ced129d2c60d1b
git push -f origin master
```

Of course, make a copy of your repository "in case of".

Comment: The very thought of a force-push to master makes me feel very awkward. Wouldn't it be safer to branch off of that SHA and merge that in instead?

Comment: Unfortunately your current commit HEAD as no common ancestor with the previous good commit, thus a merge makes little sense. Of course, make a copy of your repository "in case of".

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work. If I clone the repository... I don't get the inaccessible commits with that. It's like if they are in a 'limbo' on github and don't belong to a specific branch/tree. Also... I'm not trying to just restore the old repo... I have a partial copy of it already (from which I've got the SHA1): I could just push it. What I'm trying to do is to find the last commit available before the incident occurred...